# How does vector::assign work in C++?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

If I have the following code:

```
std::vector<char> myvector;
char myarr[10];
myvector.reserve(10);
myvector.assign(myarr, myarr + 3);
```

Will the last line (assign) work as *memcpy(&myvector[0], myarr, 3)* IF I DON'T CONSIDER UPDATING OF MEMBER VARIABLES OR RESIZE.

Comment: It should work more like `std::copy` than `memcpy`. `memcpy` is too stupid to handle a lot of things `vector` would have to deal with.

Comment: @user4581301 , what kind of things would std::copy consider in case of char? (no taking into account boundary checking)?

Comment: Read the documentation for `vector::assign`, which should tell you it changes the size of the vector. `memcpy` can't do that.

Comment: BTW, `std::copy` could be optimized for the case of trivially constructible objects to just call `memcpy`.

Comment: @JonathanWakely , that is correct and this is why I wrote "if I don't consider updating member variables"

Comment: It would be more like `myvector.resize(3);` followed by the memcpy

Comment: This is kind of like asking "would 3 + 4 = 4 IF I DON'T CONSIDER THE 3"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### OK Lets do this

By definition: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/

> Copy block of memory Copies the values of num bytes from the location
>   pointed to by source directly to the memory block pointed to by
>   destination.
>
> The underlying type of the objects pointed to by both the source and
>   destination pointers are irrelevant for this function; The result is a
>   binary copy of the data.
>
> The function does not check for any terminating null character in
>   source - it always copies exactly num bytes.
>
> To avoid overflows, the size of the arrays pointed to by both the
>   destination and source parameters, shall be at least num bytes, and
>   should not overlap (for overlapping memory blocks, memmove is a safer
>   approach).

And now for the vector: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

> Vectors are sequence containers representing arrays that can change in
>   size.
>
> Just like arrays, vectors use contiguous storage locations for their
>   elements, which means that their elements can also be accessed using
>   offsets on regular pointers to its elements, and just as efficiently
>   as in arrays. But unlike arrays, their size can change dynamically,
>   with their storage being handled automatically by the container.

Let's delve into some implementation and you will see that assign is everything, but similar to memcpy, even if you don't consider resize and member variable updates...)

Sure... It performs a copy of elements  larger or smaller in count compared to  the newly required element-count, but does memory-reallocation, bound and validity checks, etc. etc...

Memcpy just copies a block of bytes and is happy. Vector copies full-elements.

For your interest:

### GCC interface

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/libstdc++/api/a01115_source.html

```
template<typename _InputIterator>
  void
    assign(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last)
    {
        __glibcxx_check_valid_range(__first, __last);
        **_Base::assign(__gnu_debug::__base(__first),
                      __gnu_debug::__base(__last));**
         this->_M_invalidate_all();
         _M_update_guaranteed_capacity();
    }

  void
    assign(size_type __n, const _Tp& __u)
    {
        _Base::assign(__n, __u);
        this->_M_invalidate_all();
        _M_update_guaranteed_capacity();
    }

#ifdef __GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__
  void
    assign(initializer_list<value_type> __l)
    {
        _Base::assign(__l);
        this->_M_invalidate_all();
        _M_update_guaranteed_capacity();
    }
#endif
```

### _Base::assign

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-3.4/stl__vector_8h-source.html

```
void
  assign(size_type __n, const value_type& __val)
  { _M_fill_assign(__n, __val); }


template<typename _InputIterator>
  void
    assign(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last)
    {
        // Check whether it's an integral type.  If so, it's not an iterator.
        typedef typename _Is_integer<_InputIterator>::_Integral _Integral;
        _M_assign_dispatch(__first, __last, _Integral());
    }
```

### *M*-Implementation (not all of them which are required)...

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/libstdc++/api/a01117_source.html

```
template<typename _Tp, typename _Alloc>
  void
    vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::
       _M_fill_assign(size_t __n, const value_type& __val)
    {
        if (__n > capacity())
        {
            vector __tmp(__n, __val, _M_get_Tp_allocator());
            __tmp.swap(*this);
        }
        else if (__n > size())
        {
            std::fill(begin(), end(), __val);
            std::__uninitialized_fill_n_a(this->_M_impl._M_finish,
                                          __n - size(), __val,
                                          _M_get_Tp_allocator());
            this->_M_impl._M_finish += __n - size();
        }
        else
            _M_erase_at_end(std::fill_n(this->_M_impl._M_start, __n, __val));
        }
    }
```

and many more and many more...

Comment: Thank you for the clarity of the response.